# Calculated column issue with if statement and yes/no field

Tags: calculated-column

I have seen other similar questions about calculated fields/columns and Yes/No fields, but only regarding syntax.  I don't have an issue with the syntax (I think) but I can't get an `IF` statement to work with a Yes/No field.

My formula is pretty simple:

```
=IF([YesNoFieldA]="Yes","Print Some Text","Print some other text")
```

This forumula always returns the false value ("Print some other text").

When I set the formula to:

```
=[YesNoFieldA]
```

A "Yes" or "No" are always returned.

Is this a known bug, or are Yes/No fields just quirky and I can't figure them out?

Comment: For the record I loathe the yes no field, it is displayed as yes/no, stored as true/false, and is referenced in places as 1/0. I prefer to use an actual choice field instead for consistancy whenever possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes/No fields are internally stored as bit/boolean. So your first attempt of comparing the value to a string "Yes", is correctly evaluating to false, then resulting in "Print some other text" returned.

If you use this formula, then a boolean comparison will be performed, thus giving you the expected result:

```
=IF([YesNo],"Print Some Text","Print some other text")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm not a programmer by trade and this would have never occurred to me.

Answer (score 4):

Although the fields are called Yes/No fields their values are actually Boolean (i.e. TRUE/ FALSE). If you were using a different language version of SharePoint Yes/No would be translated into that language.

If you change your formula to:

```
=IF([YesNoFieldA]=TRUE,"Print Some Text","Print some other text")
```

all will be well in the world

Comment: I had tried this earlier and it didn't work.

Comment: SammyB - this does work, you probably used "TRUE" and not TRUE